# Correct way to stop a Tkinter .after loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Tkinter gui class containing several methods.  The below get_prices method ends with this self.loop line which then calls get_prices again after five minutes (300000 milliseconds).

```
def get_prices(self):
    code...
    code...
    code...
    self.loop = self.main_window.after(300000, self.get_prices)
```

I would like to have a stop button in the GUI that prevents get_prices from running again after five minutes.  So I've introduced this switch_off method into the class.

```
def switch_off(self):
    self.main_window.after_cancel(self.loop)
```

Is this the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct way to cancel something that was scheduled with `after`.